Unable to create target server in cloud APIGEE with '/' character
We're using "Contentful CMS" for backend. We need to configure the host like this "https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces//environments/" in target servers.
Is there any way to achieve this so that we could configure the URLs for DEV or TEST or PRODUCTION environments?
It displays the error message to create the host name with letters, numbers and periods.

On target servers you'll need to configure only the host, that is cdn.contentful.com, not the entire URL. The rest of the URL(i.e., /spaces//environments/) will need to be configured on the target endpoint using the Path attribute under HTTPTargetConnection.
Something like this -
<TargetEndpoint name="default">
  <HTTPTargetConnection>
      <LoadBalancer>
        <Algorithm>RoundRobin</Algorithm>
        <!-- This will be the name of the target server you've created on Environment Configuration -->
        <Server name="contentful-cms-dev" />
      </LoadBalancer>
  </HTTPTargetConnection>
  <Path>/spaces//environments/</Path>
</TargetEndpoint>

Refer the docs for more details.
